# 1.8 - Add custom dropdown to admin

Tags: magento-1.8

I've added the following observer which adds a custom text field to the CMS Page Information:

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('lcms_author_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Custom'),'class'=>'fieldset-wide'));

$fieldset->addField('author', 'text', array(
  'name'      => 'author',
  'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Author'),
  'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Author'),
  'disabled'  => false,

  'value'     => $model->getauthor()
));
```

How could I change this to be a dropdown? Ideally the select options would be generated from an attribute but I don't mind hard-coding them if it makes it 10x easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out now, you need to change `text` to `select` and add `values` as an array.  I've also added an extra line so that if a value is found in the database it is selected by default:

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('lcms_author_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Custom'),'class'=>'fieldset-wide'));

$fieldset->addField('author', 'select', array(
  'name'      => 'author',
  'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Author'),
  'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Author'),
  'disabled'  => false,
  'values'    => array('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3')
));

if ($model->getauthor()) {
  $model->setData('author', $model->getauthor());
}
```